# Remove Object in NSArray (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray

I have an NSArray (moodArray) that contains all my json, and I have another NSArray (idArray) that contains id and if idArray the id are present in moodArray should be deleted objects in the moodArray ? How to do ? Thank you

My code :

```
- (void)fetchEntries
    {
        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        [manager GET:API_V3_CHANNEL_URL parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

            NSDictionary *searchDict = responseObject;

            // On filtre le json
            NSPredicate *firstNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %@", @"LIVE"];
            NSPredicate *lastNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %@", @"PAUSE"];

            NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate]];

// My idArray
            NSArray *idArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"56ead10ae3c9a053398b4580", @"56efq10ae3c9a053398b4590", nil];

// My moodArray (content alljson)     
            self.moodArray = [[searchDict objectForKey:@"CONTESTS"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredicate];



            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];

    }
```

My moodArray (json) :
[image: My json]

I would check if moodArray contains the same id that idArray and if so delete the objects that have the same id in moodArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the JSON objects strings? If so, I would use NSJSONSerialization to convert them into a dictionary and then extract the ID.

```
-(NSDictionary*) convertJSONStringToDictionary:(NSString*)jsonString
{
    NSError         *error;
    NSData          *objectData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary    *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error:&error];
    return dictionary;
```

}

you could clean the array with something like:

```
-(NSArray*)removeIDs:(NSArray*)idArray fromArray:(NSArray*)moodArray
{
    NSMutableArray          *cleanedMoodArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *jsonString in moodArray) {
        NSDictionary    *moodDictionary = [self convertJSONStringToDictionary:jsonString];
        NSString        *objectID = [moodDictionary objectForKey:@"id"];

        if (nil != objectID) {
                if (![idArray containsObject:objectID])
                    [cleanedMoodArray addObject:moodDictionary];
        }

    }

    return cleanedMoodArray;
}
```

Comment: I think it can work but now it crash (NSExecption), that's the screenshot of my code: http://mbsolution.be/victor/capture.png

Comment: Where is the exception saying it is crashing? Have you tried running it with an exception breakpoint active?

Comment: Can I send you my .m file? If you will look or is my problem

Comment: Just make it crash, and then copy the log from the debugger.

Comment: log : [__NSCFDictionary dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa81b429090
2016-04-04 08:26:17.106 MSContestAPI[97935:2982563] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa81b429090'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: I feel that jsonString is null, no ?

Comment: so it looks like the objects are already NSDictionaries. If that is the case you don't need to do the conversions. You could just do:    
    for (NSDictionary    *moodDictionary in moodArray) {
            NSString        *objectID = [moodDictionary objectForKey:@"id"];

Comment: I think it works but instead of removing the object with the same id he just keep the object in the id

Comment: Can I ask you a question on the same topic? I have a key in the Arran is a date and that date with a condition I can detect if it is valid or not, but how I can remove the object in cleanedDictionnary when the date no longer ets valid? A bit like IDs, Thanks

Comment: Not sure I quite understand the question. You could test to see if the date is valid before adding the object to the cleanedDictionary in the first place.

Comment: No, let me explain: I test the date objects moodArray and if NSOrderedDescending I would delete the object in the same way as with IDs

Comment: If I have understood correctly you are asking how to remove objects at a later date. In this case I would try something like: NSMutableSet            *rejectSet = [NSMutableSet set];
    
    for (NSDictionary    *moodDictionary in moodArray) {
        NSDate          *objectDate = [moodDictionary objectForKey:@"date"];
        
        if (nil != objectDate) {
            if ([self functionToSeeIfDateShouldBeRejected:objectDate]) {
                [rejectSet addObject:moodDictionary];
            }
        }
        
    }
    [moodArray removeObjectsInArray:rejectSet.allObjects];

Comment: I have just a error, look: http://mbsolution.be/victor/capture3.png
(In fact I would remove objects moodArray when NSDate is NSOrderedDescending)